# Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am doing firebase authentication using reactjs but I am unable to do it. its throwing an error, `error message->  Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).`
how am I restricted ? how come its an admin-restricted-operation...
I have gone through many solution but it didn't really help....
I even created a new project on firebase but the problem still persist...

`file: firebaseConfig.js`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export default app
export const auth = getAuth(app)
```

`file: signUp.js`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '../../firebaseConfig'

//css module import 
import signupCard from './SignUp.module.css'

export const SignUp = props =>{

    //State....
    const [ credentials, setCredentials ] = useState({
        fnameRef: '', 
        snameRef:'',
        phoneRef: '',
        cityRef: '',
        dobRef: '',
        emailRef: '',
        passwordRef: '',
        passwordConfirmationRef: ''
    })

    const signupHandler = async (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()

        if(credentials.emailRef === '' && credentials.passwordRef === ''){
            console.log('empty fields!!')
        }else{
            try{
                const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.emailRef, credentials.passwordRef)
                console.log(user)
            }catch(error){
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        
        
    }

    const backHandler = () => {
        props.backButtonDetails(true)
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className = {signupCard.signupContainer}>
                
                <form onSubmit={signupHandler}>
                    <div className = {signupCard.signupFormFirst} >
                    <button onClick={backHandler} > back </button>
                        <span className = {signupCard.branding1}>SnowChild</span>
                        <hr className = {signupCard.hrTag}/>
                        <input type = 'text' className = {signupCard.fname} placeholder = 'firstname' id = 'Fname' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({fnameRef: event.target.value})}/>
                        <input type = 'text' className = {signupCard.sname} placeholder = 'surname' id = 'Sname' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({snameRef: event.target.value})}/>
                        <input type = 'text' className = {signupCard.phone} placeholder = 'phone' id = 'contact' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({phoneRef: event.target.value})}/>
                        <input type = 'text' className = {signupCard.city} placeholder = 'city' id = 'Where' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({cityRef: event.target.value})} />
                        <span className = {signupCard.dateString} >Date of birth</span>
                        <input type = 'date' className = {signupCard.dob} id = 'birthdate' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({dobRef: event.target.value})}/>
                        <hr className = {signupCard.hrTag}  style = {{margin: '20px 0 10px 0'}}/> 
                    </div>
                    <div className = {signupCard.signupFormSecond}>
                        <hr className = {signupCard.hrTag} />
                        <input type = 'email' placeholder = 'Email' className = {signupCard.UNF} id = 'email' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({emailRef: event.target.value})}/>
                        <input type = 'password' placeholder = 'Password' className = {signupCard.PWD} id = 'password' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({passwordRef: event.target.value})}/>
                        <input type = 'password' placeholder = 'confirmPassword' className = {signupCard.PWD} id = 'passwordConfirmation' onChange = {(event) => setCredentials({passwordConfirmationRef: event.target.value})}/>
                        <hr className = {signupCard.hrTag} style = {{marginTop: '10px'}}/>
                        <button type = 'submit' className={signupCard.signupButton}> Sign up </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

what am I doing wrong ??
error
[image]

Comment: I saw you shared confident information , error of information is enough , I recommend to undo confident information

Answer (score 0):

so I find out the answer but I don't know the reason behind it! it is more of an hit and trial answer....

BEFORE:

```
const [ credentials, setCredentials ] = useState({
        fnameRef: '', 
        snameRef:'',
        phoneRef: '',
        cityRef: '',
        dobRef: '',
        emailRef: '',
        passwordRef: '',
        passwordConfirmationRef: ''
    })
```

AFTER:

```
 const [currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState('')
    const [ credentials, setCredentials ] = useState({
        fnameRef: '', 
        snameRef:'',
        phoneRef: '',
        cityRef: '',
        dobRef: ''
    })
    const [ emailRef, setEmailRef ] = useState('')
    const [ passwordRef, setPasswordRef] = useState('')
```

so I convert ```emailRef and passwordRef``` to independent ```State Variables``` but Idk the explanation behind this.... but yeah it did work and now the user is being created.....

Answer (score -2):

It could be related to the 3 things below in my opinion.

It was suggested that Firebase rules are not setup correctly in this similar post [Admin operation restricted answer by](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/firebase/Auth/signInAnonymously)

The biggest suggestion from all the other threads and research I've done for you, and probably the wrong answer is found here [signing anonymously with firebase](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/firebase/Auth/signInAnonymously)

Another answer has to do with the Firebase versioning and code used found here in [Dandotwaves answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69740661)

This is the code from that post by Dandotwave:

```
import { firebase } from "@firebase/app";

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig =  {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
```

You are using

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export default app
export const auth = getAuth(app)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort but it didn't work....

Comment: I'd find a tutorial somewhere and run it's demo files to rule out it's not an issue coming from Firebase and not your code.

Comment: hey man I got I answer !! but Idk the explanation so. as you can see I have taken ```emailRef``` and ```passwordRef``` as a ```State Object Variables``` so change those to independent ```State Variables``` and it worked ! idk the reason behind it.... but yeah it did work.... ;);)

Comment: nice!!! I hope I helped some if any. Maybe reset your brain to think of something else.