# Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation) why its error in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is all setup and firebase install. There are my react.js using project.I will change to firebase config and new setup but didnt do it conloe log in show Error (`auth/admin-restricted-operation`). Why do I get this error in firebase?

My code:

```
import { Children, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { app } from "../Firebase/Firebase.config";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, } from "firebase/auth";
 


export const AuthContext = createContext(null)
 
 const auth = getAuth(app)

const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  

    const newUser=(email,password)=>{
        setLoading(true)
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password)
    }




    useEffect(() => {
        const unSubscribe = onAuthStateChanged((auth), currentUser => {
            setUser(currentUser)
            setLoading(false)
        })
        return () => {
            return unSubscribe
        }
    }, [])




 const authInfo={
    user,
    loading,
    setLoading,
    newUser,
 }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authInfo}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215748/firebase-error-auth-admin-restricted-operation-after-createuserwithemailandpassw and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102606/firebase-error-auth-admin-restricted-operation.